# Regular expression to replace markup with iframe

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm building a simple function to embed videos in Wordpress. I want to read the post content and replace `[youku: xxAAAJFSK]` with an iframe: `<iframe src="http://player.youku.com/embed/xxAAAJFSK"></iframe>`

I'm guessing I should use a regular expression to do the replacement but can't seem to find the correct one... I tried:

```
$pattern = '/youku\.com\/([^\/]*)/i';
if (preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches)){
  $id_video = $matches[1];
  return "<iframe src='http://player.youku.com/embed/" . $id_video . "></iframe>";
}
```

This just breaks my site though..

Extra points if you manage to let me set the width and height using something like `[youku: xxAAAJFSK width:400 height:400]`

Comment: It'd be useful if you included what's in `$pattern`.

Comment: Indeed.. Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you fixed to that syntax? If not, you'd be best looking at the [Wordpress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and following their style. That would take a lot of the hard work out of it for you as the system would handle the argument parsing. For example:

```
// [youku vid="xxAAAJFSK" width="400" height="400"]
function youku_func( $atts ) {    
    return "<iframe src='http://player.youku.com/embed/" . $atts['vid'] . " width='" . $atts['width'] . "' height='" $atts['height'] . "'></iframe>";
}
add_shortcode( 'youku', 'youku_func' );
```

You would probably want to expand this to include default values for width and height or remove them if they're not given as arguments.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I am now ready to handle more codes if needed in the future!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually very [easy](http://regex101.com/r/uD5mF9) to do ...

- `\[`: Match `[`
- `\s*` : Match a whitespace 0 or more times
- `youku` : Match youku
- `\s*` : Match a whitespace 0 or more times
- `:` : Match `:`
- `\s*` : Match a whitespace 0 or more times
- `([^]]*)` : Match anything except `]` 0 or more times and group it
- `\]` : Match `]`
- You may even use the `i` modifier for case insenstive matching.

**Regex:** `\[\s*youku\s*:\s*([^]]*)\]`
**Replace:** `<iframe src="http://player.youku.com/embed/$1"></iframe>`
**PHP code:** `$output = preg_replace('#\[\s*youku\s*:\s*([^]]*)\]#i', '<iframe src="http://player.youku.com/embed/$1"></iframe>', $input);`

Comment: Works like a charm! And thanks a lot for the regex explanation, it's helping me a lot. In the end, I'm still gonna use n00dle's solution though as it seems to be a more standard way to do in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're doing this for educational purposes, [don't reinvent the wheel](http://wordpress.org/plugins/proplayer/).

There are a lot of youku-enabled Wordpress plugins already.

**Edit: If you want to roll your own, I'd suggest looking at one of the existing working plugins and tailoring their implementation to suit your needs.**

Comment: I've tried a bunch of plugins before trying to do this myself, and they simply weren't working... I also had a look in the code but couldn't extract the small part that I was interested in. In the end, I'd rather do the simple stuff myself without plugin as I feel I have more control over it, especially when I'm unable to understand the plugin's code. Anyways, your thinking is valid too, thanks for sharing :)